# Javascript replace function error

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with the javascript replace function and I don't succeed to resolve it.

This is my code :  https://jsfiddle.net/r36k20sa/1/

```
  var tags = ['zazie', 'johnny'];

  tags.forEach(function(element) {
    content = content.replace(
      new RegExp("(?!<a.*?>.*?)(\\b" + element + "\\b)(?!.*?<\\/a>)", "igm"),
      '<a href="" class="esk-seo-plu-link" style="background:red;color:white">$1</a>'
    );
  });
```

In the tags array, if I reverse the array "johnny" then "zazie" all tags are well selected otherwise, some tags are missing. (The last in this example). What can be the trick?

What can be explained that ? It seems like the javascript replace function runs asynchronous?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please post the initial value of `content` that you're working with?

Comment: No, `replace` is not asynchronous.

Comment: Can you please explain how you expected your regex to work? What are these negative lookaheads good for? The first one *never* will match given your `element`.

Comment: Notice that `.` does not match linebreaks. Do you think that could explain something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you seriously using regex to process HTML when you have a DOM parser at your fingertips?

```
var content = document.getElementById('content');

function findTextNodes(root,ret) {
    // recursively descend into child nodes and return an array of text nodes
    var children = root.childNodes, l = children.length, i;
    ret = ret || [];
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( children[i].nodeType == 1) { // ElementNode
            // excluding A tags here, you might also want to exclude BUTTON tags
            if( children[i].nodeName != "A") {
                findTextNodes(children[i],ret);
            }
        }
        if( children[i].nodeType == 3) { // TextNode
            ret.push(children[i]);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
var textNodes = findTextNodes(content);

// now search those text node contents for matching tags.
var tags = ['zazie','johnny'], tagcount = tags.length, regexes, tag;
for( tag=0; tag<tagcount; tag++) {
    regexes[tag] = new RegExp("\b"+tags[tag]+"\b","i");
}

var node, match, index, tagtext, newnode;
while(node = textNodes.shift()) {
    for( tag=0; tag<tagcount; tag++) {
        if( match = node.nodeValue.match(regexes[tag])) {
            index = match.index;
            textNodes.unshift(node.splitText(index + tags[tag].length));
            tagtext = node.splitText(index);
            newnode = document.createElement('a');
            newnode.href = "";
            newnode.className = "esk-seo-plu-link";
            newnode.style.cssText = "background:red;color:white";
            tagtext.parentNode.replaceChild(newnode,tagtext);
            newnode.appendChild(tagtext);
        }
    }
}

// and done - no more action needed since it was in-place.
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/r36k20sa/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's a lovely way to achieve that ! You're great !

Comment: Just have a problem with the case the word in inside another like this :  https://jsfiddle.net/r36k20sa/8/ .   the tag 'monnaie' is underlined for the word 'monnaies' . How do you think I can fix that ?

Comment: @FrançoisDusautoir I've updated the code to use a regex with word-boundary constraints. Hopefully this solves your issue.

Comment: It seems your solution has an error because, it doesn't work anymore ? I don't succeed to find what it's wrong. https://jsfiddle.net/r36k20sa/9/

Comment: Do you think it is possible to do the same with PHP ? I tried with PHP DOM PARSER but I don't succeed in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446272/php-simple-html-dom-parser-find-word

Answer (score 0):

Please replace `.` with `\\.`

```
  var tags = ['zazie', 'johnny'];

  tags.forEach(function(element) {
    content = content.replace(
      new RegExp("(?!<a.*?>\\.*?)(\\b" + element + "\\b)(?!\\.*?<\\/a>)", "igm"),
      '<a href="" class="esk-seo-plu-link" style="background:red;color:white">$1</a>'
    );
  });
```