# PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser, Skip word replacement from certain elements

Tags: php, preg-replace, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to add link to keyword with php dom method but the problem is that it's adding links on all instances it can find. I want to skip when keyword already have a link or it's inside img alt="" or title="" attribute, similarly inside any other tag or css class.

The issue is quite similar to this one.  [PHP simple html dom parser - find word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446272/php-simple-html-dom-parser-find-word)

I tried the answer mentioned in last post with $tagsToExclude array but that's not working.

Here is the code.

```
<?php
require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = str_get_html('<html><body><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

<p>Don\'t add link on Lorems</p>

<p>Add on Lorem again.</p>

<p>An existing link on <a href="http://lorem.net">Lorem</a></p>


<img src="Lorem.jpg" alt="Lorem text" title="Lorem image"></body></html>');


$nodes = $html->find('*');

$tagsToExclude = [
    "a",
    "img"
];

foreach($nodes as $node) {

    $keyword = 'Lorem';
    $link = '<a href="http://example.com">'.$keyword.'</a>';

    if (!in_array($node->tag, $tagsToExclude)) {

        if(strpos($node->innertext, $keyword) !== false) {
            $node->innertext = preg_replace('/\b'.$keyword.'\b/', $link, $node->innertext);
        }
    }
}

echo $html->outertext;
?>
```

Thanks